# Is it possible to access m.mtime or m.ctime from share.js in derby.js?

Tags: derbyjs, racerjs

I notice that (I think) share.js creates a sub-document called m that contains mtime and ctime in my database.  Is there a derby.js way to `$orderby` based on those attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure, but you can try something like this:

```
model.query('collectionName', {$orderby: {_m: {mtime: 1}}});
```

But anyway _m, _v, _type fields will be removed before you get document from model.