# Access ShareJS metadata from DerbyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, derbyjs

DerbyJS uses ShareJS for its data synchronization. ShareJS stores various metadata values, as you can see here:

```
{ "id" : "ABCDEFG12345", "_type" : "http://sharejs.org/types/JSONv0", "_v" : 3, "_m" : { "mtime" : 1403674645713, "ctime" : 1403674645618 }, "_id" : "ABCDEFG12345" }
```

The `_type`, `_v` and `_m` fields are automatically generated by ShareJS.

I know there is a similar question over at [Is it possible to access m.mtime or m.ctime from share.js in derby.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052855/is-it-possible-to-access-m-mtime-or-m-ctime-from-share-js-in-derby-js) , but the only provided solution is that it is possible to use these fields for querying.

Is there any way to access these properties from the fetched object using Derby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. These fields are striped in ShareJS db adapter level.

[source](https://github.com/share/livedb-mongo/blob/master/mongo.js#L403-L406)